# Binary operation needed for "button that might be pushed only once"

Tags: java, binary

I have variable:

```
boolean retry_need ;
```

Which simple binary operation to apply to realize logic "button that might be pushed only once" which allows set variable to false if its current value of `retry_need` is true and not allow set back to true if it already set to false. This might be realised with function:

```
boolean  aa( boolean retry_need , boolean value)
{
if (retry_need == false) 
  {
// do nothing 
  }
else retry_need=value;
return retry_need;
}
```

But maybe this is possible to do with binary operation?

Comment: "set variable to false if its current value is true" The current `value` or the current value of `retry_need`?

Answer (score 0):

First, `function` is not a keyword in Java. Remove it.

Your method returns `true` when both `retry_need` is `true` and `value` is `true`, so:

```
static boolean aa(boolean retry_need, boolean value) {
    return (retry_need && value);
}
```

Note that the `retry_need` parameter is hiding any potential *field* of the same name, and since Java is pass-by-value, changing the parameter will not affect the variable used on the *call* to the method, so assigning a value to `retry_need` inside the method will have no effect once the method returns.